# Different Duration for Different Images

Tags: android, androidimageslider

I have used daimajia/AndroidImageSlider library. How can i set Different Duration for Different Images ?? is it possible to set different duration for images ?? For instance if there are two Categories of Images, category A duration will be 15 sec and category B will be 5 sec

```
                  for (String name : url_maps.keySet()) {
                        customSliderView = null;
                        customSliderView = new CustomSliderView(getApplicationContext());
                        // initialize a SliderLayout
                        customSliderView
                                //.description(name)
                                .image(url_maps.get(name))
                                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
                        //.setOnSliderClickListener(this);
                        mDemoSlider.addSlider(customSliderView);
                    }
                    mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.DepthPage);
                    mDemoSlider.setDuration(MY_DURATION);
                    mDemoSlider.startAutoCycle(MY_DURATION, MY_DURATION, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, After lot of trial and error I've achieved what I intended to do. I had to turn off auto cycle and swap slider manually after 17 seconds and 3 seconds periodically. Pls let me know if there is any better solution.

```
for (String name : url_maps.keySet()) {
                            //textSliderView = null;
                            customSliderView = null;
                            //textSliderView = new TextSliderView(getApplicationContext());
                            customSliderView = new CustomSliderView(getApplicationContext());
                            // initialize a SliderLayout
                            customSliderView
                                    //.description(name)
                                    .image(url_maps.get(name))
                                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.CenterCrop);
                            //.setOnSliderClickListener(this);
                            mDemoSlider.addSlider(customSliderView);
                        }

                        mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.DepthPage);
                        //mDemoSlider.setDuration(MY_DURATION);
                        mDemoSlider.destroyDrawingCache();
                        mDemoSlider.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                        mDemoSlider.clearDisappearingChildren();
                        mDemoSlider.stopAutoCycle();
                        //mDemoSlider.startAutoCycle(MY_DURATION, MY_DURATION, true);
                        //mDemoSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

And then 2 function for swapping

```
private void initViewPager() {
    //sendRequest();
    //callAsynchronousTask();
    callTimer1();
}
private void callTimer1() {
    // Auto start of viewpager
    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
            //mDemoSlider.moveNextPosition(true);
            mDemoSlider.setCurrentPosition(0, true);
        }
    };

    final Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();

    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
            swipeTimer.cancel();
            callTimer2();
        }
    }, 3500, 17000);
}

private void callTimer2() {

    final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
            mDemoSlider.setCurrentPosition(1, true);
            //mDemoSlider.moveNextPosition(true);
        }
    };
    final Timer swipeTimer2 = new Timer();
    swipeTimer2.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(Update);
            swipeTimer2.cancel();
            callTimer1();
        }
    }, 17000, 3500);
}
```